# Sinon not installing while doing npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, sinon

I am doing

> npm install Sinon

the error that I am getting is

`32 verbose stack Error: 404 Not Found: @sinonjs/formatio@^2.0.0
32 verbose stack     at fetch.then.res (C:\Users\gvqc48\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\fetchers\registry\fetch.js:42:19)
32 verbose stack     at tryCatcher (C:\Users\gvqc48\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
32 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\gvqc48\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
32 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\gvqc48\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
32 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\gvqc48\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
32 verbose stack     at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\gvqc48\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:693:18)
32 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueue (C:\Users\gvqc48\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:133:16)
32 verbose stack     at Async._drainQueues (C:\Users\gvqc48\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:143:10)
32 verbose stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (C:\Users\gvqc48\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
32 verbose stack     at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
32 verbose stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
32 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:722:5)
34 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
35 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\gvqc48\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "sinon" "--save-dev"
36 verbose node v8.9.4
37 verbose npm  v5.7.1
38 error code E404
39 error 404 Not Found: @sinonjs/formatio@^2.0.0
40 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`

I am running

> Node 8.9.4
>
> Npm 5.7.1

Comment: me too, artifactory is not finding it and neither is registry.npmjs.org

Comment: I tried all that...but no luck...saw an open issue on @sinonjs/formation which is a dependency for sinon. I followed some steps shown over there but that did not help :(

Comment: this just came back later in the day with no issues... i'm assuming something was wrong with the repo for some brief time.

Comment: I still cannot install the latest version of sinon that is 4.2.2. I tried just now and did not have any luck with that

Answer (score 1):

There's apparently some issue with the encodeURI. Which can be caused by a lot of things. The sloped slashdot for scoped packages gets turned into %2f, so you get a 404 package not found.
Long story short, **removing the ~/.npmrc file fixed it for me**. Be careful to back it up since it may also contain useful stuff in there.

Have a look here and the links in the threat: https://github.com/sinonjs/formatio/issues/14#issuecomment-371681402

Answer (score 0):

Someone was having the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008681/angular-cli-build-errors-after-npm-update#)

I was using version webpack 3.9.1 and upgraded as told there, but I am still having the issue with npm, my error message is not exactly the same but I am quite positive npm@5.7.1 is causing the issue.

Maybe you will have more luck than me, trying that bit with webpack, assuming you have it installed.

Comment: I am not using webpack. :(

Comment: Ah ^^'
It could also be useful to have the full error stack... 
To have the whole picture.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the core of the issue is lack of support for scoped packages in caches (Sinopia) and registries (Artifactory).

This issues is being tracked in https://github.com/sinonjs/formatio/issues/14, where solutions include removing `~/.npmrc` (which sometimes contain directives to always use a different registry).

Comment: thanks for your comment. I removed the directory but it did not solve this issue. I also downgraded my npm version to use 5.6.0 and still facing the same issue.